# MongoDB some data not loading into java tomcat application

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, tomcat

I am at a loss for what could be causing this problem. Essentially I have a java webapp that is connected to a hosted mongo database. I have added a new collection to the app using a new repository that looks like this.

```
public interface ContractRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Contract, String> {
public Contract findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
public List<Contract> findByOwnerCompany(Company c);
}
```

Everything worked fine data was being added to the db, and being loaded into the app. Then we pushed a new version and it no longer would pull the data from the db but there was no data loss in the DB. I added new records manually and they would show up fine. Since then we hand added all of the records back in and it worked fine until another update. Same issue.

POM:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    
        net.company.com
        applicant-tracking-system
        1.0.0

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.company.com</groupId>
<artifactId>ats-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.7</org.slf4j-version>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <debug>true</debug>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.acesinc.ats</groupId>
        <artifactId>ats-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.company.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>ats-resume-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- exclude their default logging logback so we can use log4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- include the log4j logger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
             <!--Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j-->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8-ea02</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons file upload  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <!-- These are set in the settings.xml to our nexus repo -->
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- These are set in the settings.xml to our nexus repo -->
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.v20140609</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertiesFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty/jetty.properties</systemPropertiesFile>
                <jettyXml>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty/jetty.xml,${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty/jetty-http.xml,${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty/jetty-ssl.xml,${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty/jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
                <jettyXml>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty/jetty.xml,${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty/jetty-http.xml</jettyXml>
                <war>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</war>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
                </systemProperties>
                <path>/</path>
                <url>http://localhost:1234/mymanager</url>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I should add there are other collections and repositories that have never had any problem.

Comment: Have you changed the structure of Contract class?

Comment: Actually that might be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of `Contract` has changed is possible that old data present in the database have a different structure that is not possible to load in an instance of class `Contract`.

Check the json structure of an old value of `Contract` and a new value of `Contract` to see if there are differences.

Or if you have control over the class `Contract` inspect the old version of `Contract` and the new one to see if the data can be compatible or not.

Imagine for example that if the company name has been refactored from

```
private String companyName;
```

to

```
private String name;
```

you can't extract the old data with the method

```
public Contract findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
```

Comment: What if the Contract class itself didn't change but Contract stores a company object and the company class changed could that have the same affect? I guess either way it should be storing an ID not the whole object.

Comment: Yes it can have the same effect.

Comment: Is there a reason I wouldn't see this issue locally?

Comment: What do you mean for locally? Local application and remote db? Local db and local application? The db is always the same or not?

Comment: What do you mean for locally? Local application and remote db? Local db and local application? The db is always the same or not?

Comment: Running mongo locally with `sudo mongo` and local tomcat setup

Comment: Check the records on mongo. Extract a record on the local db that is extracted by local Tomcat. Extract the same record on the remote db that you expect that should be extracted by Tomcat and that is not. Compare them to see if they are different.

Comment: Will do, regardless i added a new record to production and copied the json for the company variable into an existing record and it now shows up. Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150423/discussion-between-dylan-and-davide-lorenzo-marino).